# How to get 24bit color information by glReadPixels() on android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glreadpixels

To save processed image by OpenGL ES, I made codes as follows. And it works well.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight * 4);
mGL.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);

try {
    TJCompressor tjCompressor = new TJCompressor(bb.array(), 0, 0, mWidth, 0, mHeight, TJ.PF_RGB);
    tjCompressor.setJPEGQuality(100);
    tjCompressor.setSubsamp(TJ.SAMP_444);
    return tjCompressor.compress(0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After that, to get 24bit color information without alpha channel for saving memory and processing time, I changed the line #1 and #2 of the codes as follows.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight * 3);
mGL.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
```

And then additionally, I removed `EGL_ALPHA_SIZE` at mGL(GL10 instance)'s EGLConfig. And I passed `GLES20.GL_RGB` as internal format parameter, when GLUtils.texImage2D() method is called.

However, the result indicates there is something wrong. The result image has only black color, and when I checked the data of `bb` buffer after `glReadPixels()` method calling, I found all data is zero. I need advice. Help, plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In core GLES2, the only valid `format`/`type` combos for [glReadPixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) are:

- `GL_RGBA`/`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`
- Optional framebuffer-specific `format`/`type` queried via `glGetIntegerv` with `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT` and `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE` respectively

In GLES2 without extensions, if `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT`/`GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE` don't yield something useful, you're stuck with `GL_RGBA`/`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, unfortunately.

With GLES3, you can `glReadPixels` into the bound `GL_PACK_BUFFER`, and `glMapBufferRange` that, though again, you're limited by `format`.

I'll note that drivers are prone to emulating tightly-packed rgb8 24-bit formats, instead implementing only the better aligned formats like rgba8, rgb565, and rgba4. A renderable format exposed as "rgb8" is potentially just rgbx8 behind the scenes.

Highly driver dependent, but if you don't care about keeping the contents of the framebuffer around, you might be able to win back some memory bandwidth with [EXT_discard_framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_discard_framebuffer.txt). (or `glInvalidateFramebuffer` in GLES3)

You might also look into [EGL_KHR_lock_surface3](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_lock_surface3.txt).

Comment: Thanks for your answer in detail. I found it works normally on some other devices.